# returning scopeidentity from a stored proc in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure which is returning the scopeidentity. I dropped the table and the stored procedure to the dbml. The return type of the function is

```
return ((ISingleResult<storedocumentResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
```

In the C# code I am using the datacontext to insert a new entry into the table via the stored procedure. I need to return the scopeidentity to a calling method, but I don't know how to access it.

```
ISingleResult<storedocumentResult> result = dbc.storedocument(doc.DocumentName, doc.FileExtension);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will either be in [`result.ReturnValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.ifunctionresult.returnvalue.aspx) (which is `object`), or via `result.Single().Foo`, where `Foo` is some property on the (generated) `storedocumentResult`.

If the former, note that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is `numeric(38,0)`, so you may need `int id = (int)(decimal)result.ReturnValue;` to do the casts and conversions correctly.